# How to make sure that SQL statement is executed and only then start next code step

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, devise

I have very strange behaviour when executing my Ruby code. I make new model with `@user = User.first_or_initialize` and then I `@user.save` but what's strange is that when I after it try to with Devise helper method `sign_in @user` it fails because by that time SQL query hasn't been executed. I have seen it in console. I made `puts @user.inspect` right after `sign_in @user`. And in terminal I've got unpleasant surprise, as `puts @user.inspect` showed me `User` model without an `id` which also means that `sign_in @user` passed `User` without an `id`. And SQL query `INSERT INTO users` was made after all put was shown in terminal.

So basically my question, how can I lock ruby code execution, until SQL statement has executed? So that when I pass `@user` to `sign_in` it passes `User` model with an `id` ???

**EDIT:**

```
@user = User.where(:uid => @shop[:uid]).first_or_initialize

if @user.persisted?
  puts 'Persisted.'
  false
else
  # New customer
  ....


  @user.save

  sign_in @user
end
```

Comment: Its hard to tell, can you show us your strange part of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure your record is not getting saved and when you are inspecting record it is showing you only initialized copy of object, can you use `save!` to see if there are any exceptions or `User.first_or_create!`

```
@user = User.first_or_initialize
@user.save!
```

Comment: It saves it. I understand it's odd, but it does. but then current_user is nil

Comment: @AigarsCibuļskis can you put in entire piece of code?

Comment: It does save entry to DB, as I mentioned before.

Comment: is `@user.persisted?` returning true?

Comment: weird and are you @user.save returns true?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your model passes all validation? You should check if `.save` is returning true - if not, please check `.errors`.

A save should execute immediately if there are no validation issues.

Comment: There aren't. Can it be of slow connection? That it saves after, and just continues ruby code execution?

Comment: @AigarsCibuļskis nope, Ruby doesn't perform such things asynchronously.